# Flex List dataprovider implicit coercion error

Tags: apache-flex

I have this error that I am not sure how to fix. Please help me as I am very very new to the Flex world.

I have this function which returns an ArrayList.

```
public function createDataProvider():ArrayList
{
    ....
   return new ArrayList(imgArray);
}
```

Later, I use it here:

```
<s:List id="pubmapList"
    dragEnabled="false" dropEnabled="false" dragMoveEnabled="false"
    dataProvider="{createDataProvider}">
```

HERE, I got an error saying: implicit coercion of a value of type to an unrelated type mx.collections.ilist

I thought the IList implementation includes ArrayList. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that createDataProvider is a function. So

```
dataProvider="{createDataProvider}"
```

binds to the function, not the result from the function. Instead, try this:

```
dataProvider="{createDataProvider()}"
```

Even better would be to bind to a property, so you can use the [Binding]-metatag, for example:

```
[Bindable]
private var _array:ArrayList;

public function createDataProvider() : void
{
    ...
    _array = new ArrayList(data);
}

<s:List dataProvider="{_array}" />
```

Now any changes to _array will automatically update all bindings.